# Typo3: Constant as Page UID

Tags: typo3, fluid

I have a list of constants assigned to various page IDs (e.g. myConstant = 22). Now I'd love to replace the following link

```
<f:link.page pageUid="22" >Link</f:link.page>
```

with something like

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{myConstant}" >Link</f:link.page>
```

I haven't been able to find the right syntax to do so. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you can't access the constants directly but you can use the constants in the ts-setup.

with `plugin.tx_myplugin.settings.myPid = {$myConstant}` in the ts-setup you can access the pid in your plugin with `{settings.myPid}`

if you're not using a plugin but a TS FluidTemplate you can assign it them like this:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = fileadmin/templates/Home.html
        variables {
            pidList {
                myConstant = {$myConstant}
                myConstant2 = {$myConstant2}
            }
        }
    }
}

<f:link.page pageUid="{pidList.myConstant}" >Link</f:link.page>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a FLUIDTEMPLATE typoscript-Object, you can do it as follows in TypoScript:

```
lib.output = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.output {
#   ...
    variables {
        myPageID = {$myConstant}
    }
#   ...
}
```

In the fluid-template you can use the variables like you want:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{myPageID}" >Link</f:link.page>
```

In case the template is rendered by an extension in a controller action, you can assign the value to a setting of your plugin: `plugin.tx_<extkey>[_pi1].settings.myPageID = {$myConstant}`. Then you can use it in the fluid template like this:

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.myPageID}">Link</f:link.page>
```

In any case, you can assign that value to some TypoScript Object and read that in your template by either using the `f:cObject` ViewHelper or the `v:var.typoscript` ViewHelper from the extension `vhs`.

Comment: it seemed like this is a good solution, but then i noticed this will always render the link to the id of the current page

Comment: That probably happens because `myPageID` isn't set correctly somewhere. Try to output it using `<f:debug>{[settings.]myPageID}</f:debug>` (add the "settings." only if needed).

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like that in t3 7.6 If you want to use a ts constant (defined  in ts-constants field as oneConst) somewhere in your page fluid template you must do somthing like this:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10 {         
    variables{
        const_one=TEXT
        const_one.value={$oneConst}
        }
    }
}
```

Without the TEXT definition you *will not get the value*. Access it in your template:

```
{const_one}
```

Hint: i was not able to organize const in an array. Like

```
const{
   one=TEXT
   one.value={..}
}
```